# Magento 2.0 Add to wish list without redirect to wish list?

Tags: magento2, redirect, wishlist

How to add a product to the wish list without triggering a redirect to the wish list?

I have tried many times. Please suggest the code for me, my theme is default LUMA.

Comment: You can try these options to achieve the functionality. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/326239/44915

Answer (score -2):

Go for :Override this method `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController::addAction()` and replace this:

```
$this->_redirect('*', array('wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()));
```

with this:

```
$this->_redirectReferer()
```