# “Add to wishlist” without redirecting to wishlist page Magento 2.06

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I need to add to wishlist ajax based or customer should not redirect to wishlist page with out redirect in Magento 2 environment.

anyone have suggestion please share.

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 4):

To fix it we need to override *Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add* controller.

– add following line in module *di.xml* to tell magento to use our class instead of standard one.

Filename: **Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Add">
</preference>
```

– create the class. Basically it duplicate original method, only *$resultRedirect* updated to use referer url

Filename: **Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Add.php**

```
<?php
 
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
 
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 
/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Add extends \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add
{
    /**
     * Adding new item
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @throws NotFoundException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        ...
        /* here comes the code from original controller  */
        ...
 
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code runs fine, I'd just change the code from Filename: Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml to the following so that people don't bump into the `Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression` error. 

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Add"/>
</config>`

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to add Plugin. Add `di.xml` in etc directory

```
<type name="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add">
   <plugin name="custom_wishlist_redirect" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Wishlist\AddPlugin" sortOrder="10" />
</type>
```

Add Plugin Class

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Wishlist;

use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add;

class AddPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var RedirectInterface
     */
    private $redirectIntrface;

    /**
     * AddPlugin constructor.
     * @param RedirectInterface $redirectIntrface
     */
    public function __construct(
        RedirectInterface $redirectIntrface
    ) {
        $this->redirectIntrface = $redirectIntrface;
    }

    /**
     * @param Add $subject
     * @param Redirect $resultRedirect
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        Add $subject,
        Redirect $resultRedirect
    ): Redirect
    {
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirectIntrface->getRefererUrl());

        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go for :Override this method `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController::addAction()` and replace this:

```
$this->_redirect('*', array('wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()));
```

with this:

```
$this->_redirectReferer()
```

Comment: I think your answer is for magento 1.9X

Comment: I am looking for magento 2

Answer (score 0):

This is may not be a good way, however, you can override `Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add`. The custom execute method should return the Referer Url.

```
    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    return $resultRedirect;
```